# DevTools failed to load SourceMap ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I am facing such a problem. I have the packages web-animate and web-animations.js in my node_modules directory installed. The site does not load up. That's a critical error. How could I deal with it?

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:4200/web-animations.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
platform-browser-dynamic.js:106 Uncaught TypeError: this.reflectionCapabilities.guards is not a function
  at JitReflector.guards (platform-browser-dynamic.js:106)
  at DirectiveResolver.resolve (compiler.js:3529)
  at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:14957)
  at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (compiler.js:15854)
  at eval (compiler.js:15324)
  at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15324)
  at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (compiler.js:15139)
  at eval (compiler.js:15237)
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
JitReflector.guards
```